Selecting HLS video quality mannually
I am creating an HLS stream with different qualities and am looking for a way to manually switch between them. The way I am doing this right now is that I have 1 "auto" master playlist that contains every quality stream and allows the player to choose one depending on network conditions and also an extra master playlist for every quality level, containing the video playlist and the audio playlist.
Another way I used to do this is read the master playlist and select a video playlist matching my desired quality. I stopped doing this after I started to use Bento4 as the tool automatically demuxes audio and video and configuring separate streams is a lot more difficult than I am willing to deal with.
It feels like there should be a better way of doing this, hence asking the question. Alternatively, if there is an SDK that does what Bento4 does but does not demuxe audio and video that would be helpful too.

What are you using for playback? Usually, video players allow the user to select a fixed quality.

@jmsn I am using the AVPro player
